# How to check output of function or variable for NULL

Tags: mysql

I am bit confused with Mysql syntax. I want to check for NULL the value of ExtractValue(xml, '//order[1]/quantity[$@i]') function. It can be assign to variable or this action can be skipped. I tried this and there is syntax error:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test_for_null`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test_for_null`()
BEGIN
DECLARE xml VARCHAR(1000);
SET xml = '';
DECLARE test VARCHAR(1000);
SET test = (SELECT ExtractValue(xml, '//order[1]/quantity[$@i]');
IF (test IS NULL) THEN SELECT 1; END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_test_for_null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this (note that all `DECLARE`s are at the beginning:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test_for_null`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test_for_null`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE xml VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE test VARCHAR(1000);

    SET xml = '';
    SET test = (SELECT ExtractValue(xml, '//order[1]/quantity[$@i]');
    SELECT ISNULL(test, 1, 0);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_test_for_null;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE test VARCHAR(1000)' at line 1

Comment: I updated the question. It is inside the stored proc. @ does not work either

Comment: Query: CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test_for_null`() BEGIN DECLARE xml VARCHAR(1000); DECLARE test VARCHAR(1000); SET xml = ''; SET test = (SEL...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    IF (test IS NULL) THEN SELECT 1; END IF;
END' at line 6

Comment: I updated again. It doesn't make sense to select nothing if `test` is not null.

Comment: I modified the question, there was [$@i], I put 1 there, but still error